# Do you need to join a cancelled thread? (pthreads)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm a little confused about clean-up order when you're using PThreads with regard to cancellation.  Normally, if your thread is detached, it automatically cleans up when it terminates.  If it's not detached, you need to join it to reclaim the system resources.

The textbook I'm reading states the following which strangely sounds like joining is optional with regard to cancellation:

> "If you need to know when the thread has actually terminated, you must
>   join with it by calling pthread_join after cancelling it."

So, do I need to join a cancelled thread to free its resources - and if not, then why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLPI says this:

> Upon receiving a cancellation request, a thread whose cancelability is
>   enabled and deferred terminates when it next reaches a cancellation
>   point. If the thread was not detached, then some other thread in the
>   process must join with it, in order to **prevent it from becoming a
>   zombie thread**.

Also, since canceling a thread isn't usually done immediately (read more about "cancellation points") without joining you can't be sure the thread was actually canceled.

Comment: Would it become a zombie thread if it had been set to detached mode before being cancelled? or should I make that a new question :p

Comment: @w00te It's up to you. But the quote does say "*if the thread was not detached*". If you detach a thread there's no need (**and no way**) to join it. Once you detach a thread there's no way to make it joinable again.

Comment: The Posix standard doesn't speak of zombie threads, but if I understand the term correctly, a thread which has been detached will never become a zombie.  (Logically, detaching a thread has the same effect as telling the system to do a join on it for you, as soon as it finishes.)

Answer (score 4):

From `man pthread_join`:

> After a canceled thread has terminated, a join with that thread using
>   pthread_join(3) obtains PTHREAD_CANCELED as the thread's exit status. 
>   (Joining with a thread is the only way to know that cancellation has
>   completed.)

It seems that joining is not necessary for execution it is necessary if you want know what you did actually succeed.

Answer (score 1):

From **[Doccumentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html)** of `pthread_cancel()`:

> After a canceled thread has terminated, a join with that thread using pthread_join(3) obtains PTHREAD_CANCELED as the thread's exit status. (Joining with a thread is the only way to know that cancellation has completed.)

Comment: I understand that, but my question is - if I don't care about getting the cancel confirmation, do I still need to call pthread_join, or is this some kind of special case where the resources have already been freed and it's optional (which is what it sounds like in the quote I noted)?

Comment: @w00te: I don't think its necessary in that case.

Comment: @Als It is.  You're confusing canceling with detaching.  You don't have to join a detached thread---in fact, it is an error to do so.  Unless the thread has been detached, however, you must either do a join or detach it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: So to summarize: Cancelling a thread does not remove the entries from the table maintained by the OS it merely kills the thread But only a `join` or `detach` can remove the entries otherwise it remains hanging in the system as a zombie.

Comment: @Als Cancelling a thread doesn't even kill the thread; what it does depends on the target thread, and it can be ignored, or explicitly handled (`pthread_testcancel`).  It doesn't have any effect on the thread's joinability: only `detach` can change this.  And "The pthread_join() or pthread_detach() functions should eventually be called for every thread that is created so that storage associated with the thread may be reclaimed."  (quoted from the Posix standard)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks, As always a thorough answer from you. That clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

A thread using pthread can have following cancelling statuses:

```
 PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE
 PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE
```

If you try to cancel a thread you do not 100% know if the thread will really get cancelled. Using a join delivers the information to you if the thread was really cancelled or not. There are also cancel types to be considered and respective pthread functions for setting the cancel type and state:

```
 int pthread_setcancelstate (int state, int *oldstate);
 int pthread_setcanceltype  (int type,  int *oldtype);
```

Here is a sample code borrowed from http://www.ijon.de/comp/tutorials/threads/cancel.html

EDIT: Either I am too stupid to post a few lines of code or the formatter is really going on my nerves today. Just look up the code in the link above, please.

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong in a thread or it is stopped from with in somehow it will always be tidied up by the OS. So it's all nice and safe.

You only need to join the thread if you have to be sure it has actually stopped executing, like merging two parallel tasks. (E.g. if you have various threads working on various parts a split structure you need to join them all, as in wait until they are all finished, when you want to combine the structure again)

Comment: This is false.  Unless a thread has been detached, the system must keep it around until it is joined, in order for the join to work.  This takes resources, which means that if you do it systematically, you'll eventually run out of resources.