# segfault in pthread_join()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The below program processes `nbFiles` files using 1 worker thread per `GROUPSIZE` files. No more than `MAXNBRTHREADS` worker threads are run in parallel. A `watchDog()` thread (thread 0) is used to shepherd the `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED` identical workers. If anyone of the workers fails, it `pthread_cond_signal(&errCv)` the `watchDog` under the protection of global mutex `mtx`, passing its thread ID via the `errIndc` predicate. `watchDog` then cancels all running threads (global `oldest` maintains the ID of the oldest thread still alive to help it do this), and exits the program.

```
// compile with: gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99 -g -D_BSD_SOURCE -pthread -o pFiles pFiles.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "pthread.h"

#define INDIC_ALL_DONE_OK  -1

typedef  int_fast32_t  int32;
typedef uint_fast32_t uint32;

uint32 MAXNBRTHREADS = 10; // no more than this amount of threads running in parallel
uint32 GROUPSIZE = 10;   // how many files per thread

uint32 nbFiles, gThID;  // total #files, group ID for a starting thread

int32 errIndc = 0;  // global thread error indicator

pthread_t *thT;     // pthread table
void **retVals;     // thread ret. val. table, needed in stop_watchDog()
uint32 gThCnt;   // calculated size of thT[]
uint32 thCnt, oldest;  // running threads count (as they are created), oldest thread *alive*

pthread_cond_t  errCv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  // thread-originated error signal
pthread_mutex_t mtx   = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; // mutex to protect errIndc

// Worker thread
void *processFileGroup(void *arg) {
  int32 err;
  int last_state, last_type;
  uint32 i, thId = (uint32)(intptr_t) arg;

  fprintf(stderr, "th %ld started\n", thId);

  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &last_state);
  pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &last_type);

  // Artificial error in thread 17
  if(thId==17) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
      errIndc = (int32) thId;
      pthread_cond_signal(&errCv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_exit((void *)(intptr_t)err); }

  for(i = 0; i < GROUPSIZE ; i++) {  // simulate processing GROUPSIZE files
    pthread_testcancel();
    err = 0;
    if(usleep(10000)) { err = 1; break; }
  }

  //fprintf(stderr, "  -- th %ld done with err = %ld\n", thId, err);
  if(err!=0) { // Signal watch dog
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
      errIndc = (int32) thId;
      pthread_cond_signal(&errCv);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_exit((void *)(intptr_t) err);
  }

  pthread_exit((void *)(intptr_t) err);
}

// Mishap : cancel existing threads, exit program
int32 cancel_exit(int32 rc, int32 faultyThId, char *msg) {
  uint32 j; int32 rval;
  void *retVal;
  if(rc==0) return 0;
  if(msg!=NULL && msg[0]=='\0') fprintf(stderr, "\nError in thread %ld. Stoping..\n", faultyThId);
  else                          fprintf(stderr, "\n%s %ld. Stop.\n\n", msg, faultyThId);
  for(j = oldest; j < thCnt ; j++) pthread_cancel(thT[j]);
  for(j = oldest; j < thCnt ; j++){
    pthread_join(thT[j], &retVal); rval = (int)(intptr_t) retVal;
    //if(retVal == PTHREAD_CANCELED || rval==115390242)
    if(retVal == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
         fprintf(stderr, "  cexit: thread %ld canceled\n", j);
    else fprintf(stderr, "  cexit: thread %ld finished, rc = %ld\n", j, rval);
  }
  pthread_join(thT[4], &retVal); rval = (int)(intptr_t) retVal; fprintf(stderr, "  cexit1: thread 4 finished, rc = %ld\n", rval);
  fprintf(stderr, "Processing stopped\n\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); return rc;
}

// Watch dog thread
// it fires on signal from one of the running threads about a mishap
void *watchDog(void *arg) {
  int32 err;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (errIndc == 0) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&errCv,&mtx);
      if(errIndc == INDIC_ALL_DONE_OK){   // main() says we're done with no issues
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        err = 0; pthread_exit((void *)(intptr_t) err);
      }
    }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  fprintf(stderr, "watch dog: stopping on error indication %ld\n", errIndc);
  cancel_exit(1, errIndc, "");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); return arg;// not reached
}

void stop_watchDog() {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    errIndc = INDIC_ALL_DONE_OK;
    pthread_cond_signal(&errCv);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
  pthread_join(thT[0], &retVals[0]);
}

int main() {

  uint32 i, k;
  int32 rc;

  nbFiles = 950;
  gThCnt = 1+nbFiles/GROUPSIZE;

  if(gThCnt > MAXNBRTHREADS)
    fprintf(stderr, "running max %ld threads in parallel\n", MAXNBRTHREADS);
  else fprintf(stderr, "using %ld worker thread(s)\n", gThCnt);

  gThCnt++; // account for watchDog (thread 0)

  thT = (pthread_t *) calloc(gThCnt, sizeof(pthread_t));  if(thT==NULL) { perror("calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  retVals = (void **) calloc( (nbFiles/GROUPSIZE), sizeof(void *));  if(retVals==NULL) { perror("calloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

  // Start watch dog
  rc = pthread_create(&thT[0], NULL, watchDog, NULL);
  if(rc != 0) { fprintf(stderr,"pthread_create() failed for thread 0\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  thCnt = 1;

  i = 0; oldest = 1;
  while(thCnt<gThCnt) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
      if(errIndc != 0){   // watchDog is already tearing down the whole system, no point in creating more threads
        pthread_join(thT[0], &retVals[0]); // wait on WatchDog thread, which never returns (it cancel_exists).
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // not reached
      }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

    gThID = thCnt;
    rc = pthread_create(&thT[thCnt], NULL, processFileGroup, (void *)(intptr_t) gThID);
    if(rc != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,"pthread_create() failed for thread %ld\n", thCnt);
      stop_watchDog();
      cancel_exit(1, (int32)thCnt, "Could not create thread");
    }
    thCnt++;
    if(thCnt>MAXNBRTHREADS) {  // wait for the oldest thread to finish
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        if(errIndc != 0) {   // watchDog is already tearing down the whole system, he'll report the rc of thread "oldest"
          printf("[MAXNBRTHREADS] errIndc=%ld, joining watchDog\n", errIndc);
          pthread_join(thT[0], &retVals[0]); // wait on WatchDog thread, which never returns (it cancel_exists).
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // not reached
        }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
      pthread_join(thT[oldest], &retVals[oldest]); rc = (int)(intptr_t) retVals[oldest];
      fprintf(stderr, "[MAXNBRTHREADS] Thread %ld done with rc = %ld\n", oldest, rc);
      oldest++;
    }
  }
  k = oldest;
  while(k<thCnt) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
      if(errIndc != 0){   // watchDog is already tearing down the whole system, he'll report the rc of thread k
        pthread_join(thT[0], &retVals[0]); // wait on WatchDog thread, which never returns (it cancel_exists).
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // not reached
      }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    pthread_join(thT[k], &retVals[k]); rc = (int)(intptr_t) retVals[k];
    fprintf(stderr, "Thread %ld done with rc = %ld\n", k, rc);
    oldest = ++k;
  }

  // Signal watch dog to quit
  stop_watchDog();

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Line 82 causes this program to segfault. Why ? Is it illegal to join a canceled thread ?

If you comment line 82, other issues show up. If you run the program 3 of 4 times you witness one of theses pathological outcomes :

How can thread 11 have two different exit codes ?

```
.. 
watch dog: stopping on error indication 17

Error in thread 17. Stoping..
th 19 started
  cexit: thread 11 finished, rc = 115390242
[MAXNBRTHREADS] Thread 11 done with rc = -1
```

Sometimes the program will hang in MAXNBRTHREADS section :

```
...
[MAXNBRTHREADS] errIndc=17, joining watchDog
```

There is apparently a race condition in this section; but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well, I would change something to make it cleaner, safer and easier to debug.  The whole design, probably;(

Comment: @Martin: well, I dispatch the files I have to process to a bunch of threads, limiting myself to a max number of threads. If anyone thread fails, the whole process is pointless, so I make them workers cancel-able. My design is to use a watch dog to do.. the dog watching and stop the herd in case of mishap. That's the simplest design I could come up with for my use case. Any helpful ideas welcome.

Comment: It is fine to join a cancelled thread, and it is probably not the reason of the segmentation fault. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975395/do-you-need-to-join-a-cancelled-thread-pthreads

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Line 82 causes this program to segfault. Why ? Is it illegal to join a canceled thread ?

POSIX does not say that in so many words, but it certainly seems to imply so.  [The specifications for `pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) say:

> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread argument to pthread_join() does not refer to a joinable thread.

and later, in the RATIONALE,

> If an implementation detects use of a thread ID after the end of its
>   lifetime, it is recommended that the function should fail and report
>   an [ESRCH] error.

The segfault you observe is not consistent with the (non-normative) recommendation in the rationale, but the rationale does support the proposition that a thread is no longer a "joinable thread" after its lifetime has ended (e.g. because it has been canceled), for otherwise the recommendation would be inconsistent with the function's specified behavior.  Certainly threads that have already been joined are no longer joinable, though the reason to use "joinable" instead of "live" or similar is probably more the provisions for detaching threads.

> How can thread 11 have two different exit codes ?

It can't, and your output does not demonstrate otherwise.  You are joining thread 11 twice, so at least one of those `pthread_join()` calls must fail.  In the event that it does, you cannot rely on any result value that it might have stored (not based on POSIX, anyway).  You ought to check the return values of your function calls for error flags.

> Sometimes the program will hang in MAXNBRTHREADS section

Yes, it appears that it could do.

The idea here appears to be that in the failure case, the main thread will call `stop_watchDog()`, which will set a flag to advise the watchdog thread that it should stop, and then signal the condition variable to make the watchdog wake up and notice it.  When it does wake up, the watchdog thread must re-acquire mutex `mtx` before it can return from `pthread_cond_wait()`.

After returning from `stop_watchDog()`, the main thread locks mutex `mtx` and 
attempts to join the watchdog thread.  But signaling a CV is not synchronous.  It is therefore possible that the main thread locks the mutex before the watchdog thread reacquires it, in which case you will deadlock: the watchdog cannot return from `pthread_cond_wait()` and proceed to terminate until it acquires the mutex, but the main thread will not unlock the mutex until the watchdog terminates.

I haven't analyzed the program enough to be sure exactly what state the main thread needs to protect there, though it appears to include at least the `errIndc` variable.  Any way around, however, it does not appear to need to hold the mutex locked while trying to join the watchdog thread.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped me fix all the issues in my code. You're right, double-joining is no-no. That answers the segfault pb. Next bug: err is uninitialized in the "artificial error" section in the worker. Duh. Indeed, there is no need to lock for joining watchDog. Locking is needed only to read errInc (atomically). But that doesn't guarantee it won't change afterwards, if that happens main() and watchDog() are both going to join()..

Comment: And the solution to that is to simply protect all access to `oldest` with a dedicated mutex (especially in `cancel_exit()`). Problem disappears after that. That solves the issue of `main()` and `cancel_exit()` joining the same thread a split second apart.

Comment: After doing away with the cv, that is. To Martin James' point, there is a simpler design : condition vars are not needed at all, mutexes are more than enough in this use case.